# Setting Elasticsearch client object as instance variable in Apache Beam transform causes serialization error in Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, serialization, apache-beam, dataflow

In one of my Apache Beam transforms I write data to Elasticsearch, which is running locally in a Docker container. This is done by creating an Elasticsearch client, and passing it to the transform. In the transform I have an `__init__` function that sets the Elasticsearch client as an instance variable: `self.es_client = es_client`, which is then used by the `process` function to write data to Elasticsearch.

The problem is that I can't do this. Whenever I set the value of an instance variable in this transform to the client object, I receive the error ***"TypeError: Cannot serialize socket object"***.

My best guess at what's happening is that Apache Beam automatically serializes any instance variables in a transform, and it's unable to serialize this Elasticsearch client object for some reason.

The closest thing I've found online is [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/3191) issue. I'm quite confused about why this happening, but would appreciate any insights!

File that creates Elasticsearch client and passes it into the Beam transform:

```
es_client = Elasticsearch([
  {
    'host': "0.0.0.0", 'network.host': "0.0.0.0", 'network.publish_host': "0.0.0.0", 'http.port': 9200,
    'timeout': 30, 'retry_on_timeout': True, 'max_retries': 10
  }
])
....
# Line where I call the transform (as part of larger pipeline)
"Insert sessions into Elasticsearch" >> beam.ParDo(transforms.WriteDataToElasticsearch("sessions", es_client))
```

File with the transform

```
class WriteDataToElasticsearch(beam.DoFn):
  def __init__(self, index_name, es_client):
    # What index to write to
    self.index_name = index_name
    self.es_client = es_client

  def process(self, element):
    # Doesn't even get to this line - error seems to be thrown at conclusion of __init__ method
    index_exists = self.es_client.indices.exists(index=self.index_name)
    if not index_exists:
      print('Creating index {i}'.format(i=self.index_name))
      self.es_client.indices.create(index=self.index_name)

    print('Writing to {i} index'.format(i=self.index_name))
    res = self.es_client.index(index=self.index_name, body=element)
    print(res)
    yield
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Have the same thing happening with statsd.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it for myself, hopefully it works for others as well. I needed to use the statsd client in Apache Beam on Google Dataflow.

```
class SendToStatsD(beam.DoFn):
    def start_bundle(self):
        self.statsd_client = statsd.StatsClient(<ip>, <port>)
    def process(self):
        # use self.statsd_client
```

Comment: sorry for late reply, I ended up using a workaround. I instantiate a global client outside of the transform but in the same file. I only pass in the `port` and `host` to the transform, and the transform calls a method `set_global_client(host, port)`, which sets the global client variable to an elasticsearch client. Then the transform uses that global client to store data.